# Does ExecuteNonQuery wait for the triggers to be completed or it finishes once the insert/update is done?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, triggers, executenonquery

Say I have a table 'tableA'. this table has an insert/update trigger.
now through the code I fire a insert or an update query on this 'tableA' using ExecuteNonQuery().

Now my question is:
does ExecuteNonQuery wait for the triggers too to be completed or it finishes once the insert/update to 'tableA' is done?

Comment: The `insert/update` will only be done after all triggers are done. So yes even `ExecuteNonQuery` will have to wait

Answer (score 1):

*The `INSERT` itself* waits for triggers to be completed, and does not complete until then; `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't get a vote on the matter.

Comment: ok. So you mean if a break point is set on ExecuteNonQuery line, the cursor would come to the next line only if the insert on 'tableA' and the trigger is fired. Correct?

Comment: @user3840165 the next line will be triggered when ADO.NET reports the operation is complete - nothing more complex than that; the *sql server* won't do that until it is happy, but: nothing above the RDBMS knows or cares about that

Comment: could you please elaborate on this.?

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear, but: ADO.NET *doesn't know or care* what your command / query / etc is doing; all it knows is that the TDS protocol (the network language that SQL Server talks) specifies a reply that indicates when an operation is complete; ADO.NET won't complete until it gets this reply, but: **it doesn't know or care about the details** - it has no knowledge of triggers etc. It is SQL Server itself that doesn't issue the "yep, that's done" until the insert *which includes the triggers* is complete.